# Ruby on Rails: Query where date equals another date (ignoring time)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I'm trying to execute this query on my model but I can't figure it out.

- An event has a date.
- I have an array of date called "array_of_dates", I have built it from another model:

  ```
  array_of_dates = []
  user.each do |user|
     array_of_dates << user.birthday_date
  end
  ```
- user.birthday_date is of course a datetime

I tried

```
Event.where("date in (?)", array_of_dates)
```

However, date from Event also has a time set. I would like to ignore the time that has been set here, because I am just looking for the day. I have tried parsing user.birthday_date to another format, but I don't know how to change the format of "date" from the Event model.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 8):

Use the [date](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-datetime.html) function:

```
# if user's birthday_date column is date
Event.where("date(date) in (?)", User.pluck(:birthday_date))

# if user's birthday_date column is timestamp
Event.where("date(date) in (?)", User.select("date(birthday_date)"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes birthday_date is a timestamp (it's not actually a birthday date but it was easier to explain it that way).

Answer (score 1):

First transform the `array_of_dates` dates by converting each date into a range that covers the entire day:

```
array_of_dates = array_of_dates.map {|date| date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day}
```

This will convert each date into a range such as `(Mon 27 Oct 2014 00:00:00..Mon 27 Oct 2014 23:59:59)`

Now use the following query format to find the events:

```
Event.where(date: array_of_dates)
```